# Using Visual Studio on Zorin 7 Linux OS?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, unix, visual-studio-2012

Zorin is a version of Linux which is very Windows-like. I am looking at their home page:

http://zorin-os.com/

and it says:

> Zorin OS gives users more flexibility. It allows you to use Zorin OS
>   alongside your current operating system **and run Microsoft Windows
>   programs in Zorin OS with the help of WINE and PlayOnLinux**.

Does this mean I could use Visual Studio 2012 on Linux?!?!

Comment: So...not to burst your bubble, but this is probably not going to be the case (going off of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012)). Basically, WINE can be installed on Zorin, but that doesn't mean that all Windows programs are compatible with WINE.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so Wine is a [compatibility layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_layer) which allows you to execute windows executables on your linux system. PoL is just a graphical frontend with some others functionalities.
You can use it on any linux system, it's not exclusive to Zorin.

However, executing windows applications through wine isn't always successful, especially with huge projects as Visual Studio which is using tons of native windows functionalities.

And indeed, when we check [the reports](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26354), VS2012 doesn't work at all.
You can always try to install it, but when even the installer doesn't launch... You know there is no luck.